# Are $\Bbb R^2\backslash\{(x,y) : x\le 0,y=0\}$ and the unit disc homeomorphic? Difference between conformal map an homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, mobius-transformation

The [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) says that there exsists a (bijective) conformal map $f$ between $\Omega =\Bbb C\backslash \{z\in\Bbb C: Im(z)=0, Re(z)\le0\}$ and the unit disc $D_1$.

$f$ is the composition of $\sqrt{z}$ and some Möbius transformation (I think $\frac{-iz-i}{iz-i}$) and $\sqrt z$ is not continuous.

But $f$ must be "biholomorphic" so holomorphic $\implies$ continuous

How can $f$ be continuous?

Comment: Why should it be homeomorphic to the unit disc ? One is compact, the other one is open and unbounded... Difference between conformal mapping and homeomorphism ? It's quite huge : one is analytic, the other one is only continuous.

Comment: You are quoting Riemann Mapping Theorem wrongly. $\Omega$ is conformally equivalent to the open unit disk, not the closed unit disk.

Comment: If I understood correctly the slightly (or pretty...) confusing definition of that set, $\,\Omega\,$   is the plane without the whole $\;x\,-$ axis ($\,y=0\,$) and without all the points with non-positive $\;x\,-$ entry ($\,x\le0\,$). So it basically is the right half plane without the $\;x\,-$ axis...It isn't even path connected as there isn't  path within $\,\Omega\,$ between $\;(1,-1)\;$ and $\;(1,1)\;$ , for example...what am I missing here?

Comment: $\Omega$ is simply connected, it's the whole plane minus the half line $\{x\le 0,y=0\}$

Comment: "and $\sqrt z$ is not continuous" On $\Omega$, the usual square root is very much continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\Omega$ is open and simply connected. It does not contain $0$. The principal value $\sqrt{\cdot}$ of the square root function, given by
$$z\mapsto w:=\exp\bigl({1\over2}{\rm Log}(z)\bigr),$$
is analytic, hence continuous on $\Omega$. As is well known this function maps $\Omega$ bijectively onto the open half plane $H: \>{\rm Re}(w)>0$, and a suitable Moebius transformation will then map $H$ onto $D$.